# How to get JavaScript Object from '[object Object]' string?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a WebView app in React Native, and I need to handle the messages sent by website (using `postMessage`) using the `onMessage` callback. As per the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage) -

> window.postMessage accepts one argument, data, which will be available
>   on the event object, event.nativeEvent.data. data must be a string.

But the the string (`event.nativeData.data`) that I am getting in my `onMessage()` function is `'[object Object]'` which I know is the result of calling [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Syntax) method on an Object.

**Is there any way to get back the JavaScript Object obj from the resulting String obtained using obj.toString() ?**

I tried JSON.parse() but it only gives the error as shown in the attached image below.

[image: Console Output of JSON parse and toString]

Thanks !

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` to convert Object to String, `JSON.parse` for vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get back the JavaScript Object obj from the resulting String obtained using obj.toString() ?

No. The data in the object simply does not appear in the string.

You can tell this just by looking at the string! There is nothing that either resembles the original data nor which looks like an encoded *something*.

If you want to preserve the data, then use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a string instead of converting it with `.toString()`.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks so much !